# Why aren't data repositories static?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I was looking at the `repository` method for an `ASP.NET` MVC app and noticed a `static` class wasn't used.

Since the repo is `CRUD`, why not make it `static`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1) It's difficult to do unit testing with static classes (if you are testing a class that depends on your repository, you want that test to work against a fake 'mocked' repository object instead of your real one)

2) You often want to have 1 repository instance per-request to make it easier to ensure that uncommited changes from one user don't mess things up for another user.

Comment: Ah point number 2 was missing from my brain. Thanks Robert :)

Comment: I don't get the second point. Aren't static classes one instance by definition? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Anar - the difference is 1-instance vs. 1-instance-per-request

Comment: I guess I understood that long time ago :). Thank you for answering anyway, Robert.

Comment: From my experience static classes are easy to unittest since they are always constructed in a stateless fasion, so only input does affect output. With classes with internal states, it can be nearly impossible to know if all combinations are covered by the tests.

Comment: actually you cant mock a static class since they cant implement an interface

Comment: @Robert you're not doing a unit test at that point, it's an integration test nor are you isolation a block of code. That's why static classes aren't good for unit testing. No mocking or faking

Answer (score 0):

Repository pattern increase testability, static classed decreases it.

Comment: don't write comments write answers